# Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer cannot play audio from stream in Xamarin.UWP (Using Xamarin Forms App)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am working on a cross-platform application for windows and mobile.

I tried to create a sine wave stream and playing it with the help of Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer using the following code:

```
var mStrm = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(mStrm);

        const double TAU = 2 * Math.PI;
        int formatChunkSize = 16;
        int headerSize = 8;
        short formatType = 1;
        short tracks = 1;
        int samplesPerSecond = 44100;
        short bitsPerSample = 16;
        short frameSize = (short)(tracks * ((bitsPerSample + 7) / 8));
        int bytesPerSecond = samplesPerSecond * frameSize;
        int waveSize = 4;
        int samples = (int)((decimal)samplesPerSecond * msDuration / 1000);
        int dataChunkSize = samples * frameSize;
        int fileSize = waveSize + headerSize + formatChunkSize + headerSize + dataChunkSize;
        // var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        writer.Write(0x46464952); // = encoding.GetBytes("RIFF")
        writer.Write(fileSize);
        writer.Write(0x45564157); // = encoding.GetBytes("WAVE")
        writer.Write(0x20746D66); // = encoding.GetBytes("fmt ")
        writer.Write(formatChunkSize);
        writer.Write(formatType);
        writer.Write(tracks);
        writer.Write(samplesPerSecond);
        writer.Write(bytesPerSecond);
        writer.Write(frameSize);
        writer.Write(bitsPerSample);
        writer.Write(0x61746164); // = encoding.GetBytes("data")
        writer.Write(dataChunkSize);
        {
            double theta = frequency * TAU / (double)samplesPerSecond;
            // 'volume' is UInt16 with range 0 thru Uint16.MaxValue ( = 65 535)
            // we need 'amp' to have the range of 0 thru Int16.MaxValue ( = 32 767)
            double amp = volume >> 2; // so we simply set amp = volume / 2
            for (int step = 0; step < samples; step++)
            {
                short s = (short)(amp * Math.Sin(theta * (double)step));
                writer.Write(s);
            }
        }
        mStrm.ToArray();
        mStrm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var audio = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
        
        audio.Play();
        writer.Close();
        mStrm.Close();

    }
```

I am using Xamarin.Forms project and this works almost correctly in my android emulator. And by 'almost correctly' I mean the audio is crackling when played back. Anyways, the real issue is When I try to deploy the app to UWP, there is just silence, no audio to be heard.

It gets more interesting when I try to get a stream from a file. For example using the code below:

```
static Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SignalApplication." + filename);

        return stream;
    }
```

I can get a stream from a wav file placed in shared folder using the method above.

e.g.

```
var stream1 = GetStreamFromFile("sinePeriodical.wav");

                var audio = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;

                stream1.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                audio.Load(stream1);
                audio.Play();
```

Now, I think this is essentially the same thing except I am now getting the stream from a file. And this code works in both UWP and Android, I can hear the audio on both platforms. Which brings me back to the question, Why does my own generated sine wave stream only work in Android and not in UWP? Am I missing something here? The only thing that I suspect is that maybe the streams are somehow of different nature. One of them is Stream and the other is MemoryStream, maybe thats causing issues? Is there some way that I create a sine wave stream like I get from the audio file? I am looking forward to solutions or suggestions. Thank you so much

Best regards
Yawar

Comment: https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/issues/99

Comment: Checked the code you posted in the end, I noticed that the stream you are using is just an empty stream that you created like ` MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();`, not the stream1 that gets from the file. Is the the real code that you are using?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT No, Its actually stream1. Thats a typo, sorry. I have updated the question. The original code is using stream1 but still having the same issues as I described in the question. Thanks for noticing. I am very confused why would the stream from file play nicely in UWP but not the stream that I generate myself. In android, both self generated stream and stream from file works. Very strange.

Comment: @Jason, the link you posted in your comment takes me to an issue about loading a stream from fille. In my case, if I load a stream from file, it works on both UWP and Android. The issue that I am having is different. It is the self generated stream that is not working in UWP. Although the self generated stream works fine in Android. In all cases, using the same SimpleAudioPlayer.

Comment: Have you tried using the native UWP MediaPlayer to play your steam? Does it work?

Comment: No, I haven't. I am using cross-platform development environment. Haven't tried that yet.

Comment: why are you calling `audio.Play();` **before** `writer.Close();`?

Comment: @Jason, that's because it throws me an exception, "cannot access a closed stream", if I call audio.Play() before writer.Close().

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please make a try using the native UWP MediaPlayer to make sure if the steam could be played correctly.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I solved the problem. The code works on UWP now. The only problem I have now is that I cannot make the beep continuous. It plays for a certain duration (which I give as input). I am looking for a way to make the beep play continuously until it is stopped manually(like a button for example, which starts and stops the beep). Unfortunately, the "Loop" feature of Xamarin.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer is useless, as there is a longer gap between replays. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I am trying to achieve a tone generator, I used the same functionalities for web using Tone.js library, which is javascript basically. Its a very powerful library. I want to achieve the same in mobile platforms. Where I can create a simple tone, and then change the frequency on the fly. Seems like there aren't many libraries for .net. Xamarin.Forms is making things more difficult as it adds one more layer over the native environment. I want to do it cross-platform.