# Playing audio in Xamarin UWP crashes

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am building a Xamarin app for UWP (Target Version 10.0.19041.0) and I am trying to play audio through my speakers based on a certain condition. It utilizes the Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer (version 1.6.0) to do this (I have not been able to load/use the built-in MediaPlayer).

Based on the other StackOverflow questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900563/xam-plugin-simpleaudioplayer-cannot-play-audio-from-stream-in-xamarin-uwp-using) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256176/how-to-play-sounds-on-xamarin-forms))  similar to this one, I made a function that should allow me to load a .mp3 or .wav as a stream and then use the Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer to play it through my speakers.

Here is the definition of my function that attempts to load audio files as a stream. I have two files in the Assets folder of my UWP app, *beep.wav* and *beep.mp3*, both with Build Action set to Content.

```
Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename) {
    var assembly = typeof(Application).GetType().Assembly;

     var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
         "Assets/" + filename // have also tried "Assets." since that was in a stackoverflow response
     );
     return stream;
}
```

Here is the function that calls the GetStreamFromFile function. I included all the nested conditionals/switches/etc. just in case that could be a possible reason for the issue. If I comment out the audio code lines, my code runs without error and with the expected behavior.

```
private void AddOrUpdateData() {
    InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        ...
        switch (SensorType) {
             case 0:
                 ...
             case 1:
                 ...
             default:
                 try {
                     ...
                 }
                 finally {
                     if (my_value < 20) {
                         var stream = GetStreamFromFile("beep-09.mp3");
                         // stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Have tried with and without this, not really sure what Seek does
                         var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
                         audio.Load(stream);
                         audio.Play();
                     }
                     ...
                 }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

When this code runs, I get the null reference exception:
*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*
It occurs whenever 'stream' is called; if stream.Seek is uncommented, it crashes there, otherwise it crashes when audio.Load(stream) occurs since stream appears to be None.

If I try to do it without a stream, and just loading the file from the AudioPlayer, I get this error:
*System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'*
The code for that looks like this:

```
var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
// Have tried both the mp3 and wav, with/without the Assets directory, all get the same error
audio.Load("Assets/beep.mp3");
audio.Play();
```

Are there any suggestions on how to fix this? I would try to use MediaPlayer but I cannot seem to import it correctly in Xamarin Forms since I am coding within a generic C# file that compiles to all of my platforms. I am also not sure if it has something to do with the nested locks, switches, and conditionals that maybe mess up how the rest of the code runs (I am not an expert at Xamarin so there are likely processes going on above my head).

Comment: I believe that `GetManifestResourceStream` works with embedded resources

Comment: Hi @Jason, thank you for the suggestion, I changed my beep.mp3 file to an Embedded Resource, but I still get errors. The null reference still occurs on my stream variable if I try to do the stream.Seek method. If i don't use the .Seek, I get an error on the audio.Load() line that says "System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'"

Answer (score 0):

If you put files(e.g. `beep.mp3`) in the `Assets` folder of your UWP app,you can try the following code:

```
var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;

player.Load("beep.mp3");

player.Play();
```

**Note:**  Here you don't need add `Assets` as the prefix.And make sure set the build action to `Content`.

```
audio.Load("Assets/beep.mp3");
```

There is samples  here [SimpleAudioPlayer](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/tree/main/SimpleAudioPlayer/Samples), you can refer to it's code.

When you put your files in the folder of  xamarin forms, we can use following code to get the stream:

```
Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SAPlayerSample." + filename);

        return stream;
    }
```

And use following code to load the mp3:

```
 ISimpleAudioPlayer player;

 var stream = GetStreamFromFile("Diminished.mp3");
 player = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
 player.Load(stream);
```

And use  function `Seek` to seek to the special postion.

```
player.Seek(sliderPosition.Value);
```

For more information, you can check sample: [LibraryAudioPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/blob/main/SimpleAudioPlayer/Samples/SAPlayerSample/SAPlayerSample/Pages/LibraryAudioPage.xaml.cs) .